# mongo Data is not returned

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My problem with this code.

```
ask.find({nchapter:1},function(err,user){
    res.json(user);
});
```

Mongo does not return any value.
But if we remove the item, the code works fine.

```
ask.find({},function(err,user){
    res.json(user);
});
```

And returns all the data in the database.My Database Collections [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jncpk.jpg) And all other collections work well.
And my schema database [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGNoT.jpg).

Why do you think this code does not work?

```
ask.find({nchapter:1},function(err,user){
    res.json(user);
});
```

All code :

```
var ask = mongoose.Schema({
nchapter:{
    type:Number,
    min: 0,
    max: 999,
    required:true,
    trim: true,
},
nlesson:{
    type:Number,
    min: 0,
    max: 999,
    required:true,
    index:true,
    trim: true,
},
ask:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
},
ta:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
},
tb:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
},
tc:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
},
td:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
},
answer:{
    type:Number,
    required:true,
    trim: true,
},});
```

and

```
var ask = mongoose.model("ask",ask);
app.post('/getask',function(req,res){
    var reqAsk={
        nchapter:req.body.code_c,
        nlesson:req.body.code_l
    };
    ask.find({nchapter:1},function(err,user){
        res.json(user);
    });
});
```

Comment: have you tried adding `if (err) {console.log(err)}` before sending the response to find out if it is throwing any errors?. if you are trying to returns all documents but only include the `nchapter` in it then you need to put that as the second argument. not the first.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Put your collection here instead of screen shots

Comment: `nchapter.type`  is a Number and `err` is null

Comment: What are you expecting to be returned? Can you provide an example document from your collection?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using the `trim` property on fields where the `type:number`.

Comment: Can you confirm if your collection does have the document with nchapter with value 1?

Comment: (https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2018/5/22/9db89a5bb1dbab972fd88bc3045ab416-full.png) my collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared the nchapter as Number but saved all data in your DB as String. So the find query cannot find anything, but without any parameters, all your data is returned.
Good luck